# Row number functionality in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

How can I generate row numbers for an existing table while running a select query?
For example:

```
select row_number(), * from emp;
```

I am using hive 0.13. I can't access external jars or udfs in my environment.
The underlying files are in parquet format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you try to run this kind of analytic functions on large data sets (i.e. over 50 million rows) then be careful to test your data consistency. I have seen subtle **data corruption** occur in a **deterministic way** with V0.13 and V0.14 -- the row numbers were in sequence but some thousands of rows had been dropped and replaced by a copy of other rows. But that may be specific to Hive-on-TEZ.

Answer (score 36):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is a [windowing function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) so it needs to be used in conjunction with an `OVER` clause.  Just don't specify any `PARTITION`.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_num
FROM emp
--- other stuff
```

Comment: appears to need an explicit ordering at least in my version of hiveql, e.g. `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_emp_field) AS row_num FROM emp`

Answer (score 16):

row_number() can be used to find **for example**, recent visit of a user on your site.

```
SELECT user_id,user_name,timestamp
FROM (
SELECT user_id,user_name,timestamp,row_number() over (partition by userid order by timestamp desc) as visit_number 
from user) user_table
    WHERE visit_number = 1
```

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's question?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 - I have added one more layer of explanation to my answer , generate row_number and make some sense out of it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please consider adding comment , how this answer can be improved?

Comment: At least useful to me.

Comment: Subqueries and row_number should never be together