# Hive / SQL query for top n values per key

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

[image]

I want top 2 valus per key. The result would look like:

[image]

What should be the hive query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mx2NaLgzvYLvq3gGLkYvZG/0) with [OVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476952/row-number-functionality-in-hive)() close:

```
select col1,col2 from (SELECT col1,
col2, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS row_num
FROM data)f
WHERE f.row_num < 3
order by col1,col2
```

Comment: Suppose I have another column col3 and I want to display the value of col3. So I am writing following code:
    select col1,col3,col2 from (SELECT col1,col3,
    col2, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col3 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS 
    row_num
    FROM data)f
    WHERE f.row_num < 3
    order by col1,col2

But I am getting error. How to solve this

Comment: please share the error and an example of the table and version you're using.

Comment: Table:

CREATE TABLE data (
    Id Serial,
    col1 VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    col3 varchar(70),
    col2 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

INSERT INTO data
    (col1,col3, col2)
VALUES
    ('a','p', '43'),
    ('a','p', '11'),
    ('b','q', '65'),
    ('b','q', '33'),
    ('c','r', '11'),
    ('c','r', '22'),
    ('c','r', '33'),
    ('a','p', '55')
;

Query:
select col1,col2,col3 from (SELECT col1,
col2, col3
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col3 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS row_num
FROM data)f
WHERE f.row_num < 3
order by col1,col2

Comment: Error:
Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col3 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS row_num FROM data)f WHERE' at line 2

Comment: you're missing a comma after col3
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mx2NaLgzvYLvq3gGLkYvZG/0

Comment: After adding comma It's showing same error.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6QXPWbvt9XwZTpbsecBYeL/3

Comment: try this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6QXPWbvt9XwZTpbsecBYeL/4 with postgres. closer to hive

Comment: Can I run this query on hive ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173581/discussion-between-ereli-and-kallol).