# Customised ordering in Hive's row_number() over partition by order by window function

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, window-functions

I have a table with an identifier column `id` and another column with string values `column_b` for which I would like to do customer ordering on `column_b`. Let's say that `column_b` consists of values *A, B, C, D*.

The syntax that can be used in Hive for row_number() over() is:

```
SELECT id, column_b, row_number() over(partition by id order by column_b) as row_id
FROM   some_table
```

Example see here for an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476952/row-number-functionality-in-hive)

However, I would like to do *custom ordering* on `column_b` instead of alphabetic ordering. The above syntax would yield something like:

[image]

Instead, I would like to explicitly order by column_b using the order `A, C, D, B`, that is:

[image: hive]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly specify the order using case statement. You can use other scalar functions in the `order by`:

```
SELECT id, column_b, 
       row_number() over(partition by id order by case column_b
                                                       when 'A' then '1'
                                                       when 'C' then '2'
                                                       when 'D' then '3'
                                                       when 'B' then '4'
                                                       --add more cases
                                                       --for example other values sort
                                                       --in natural order  
                                                       else column_b 
                                                       --or use constant
                                                       --to make sure 
                                                       --everything else is greater than 4 
                                                       --like this  else concat('5',column_b)
                                                  end 
                         ) as row_id
  FROM some_table
```

Also you can calculate order column in the subquery and use it in the window, it will work the same:

```
SELECT id, column_b, 
       row_number() over(partition by id order by orderby) as row_id
  FROM (select t.*, 
               case column_b
                    when 'A' then '1'
                    when 'C' then '2'
                    when 'D' then '3'
                    when 'B' then '4'  
                    else concat('5',column_b) 
               end orderby
           from some_table t
        ) s
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I prefer the first version since it's easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below simple query,

```
select id, column_b,row_id from
(select id, column_b,row_id from table order by mod(row_id,2) != 0
union all
select id, column_b,row_id from table order by mod(row_id,2) = 0) qry;
```